# Why is it that some regex match is not replaced one by one?

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-lookarounds

I am using notepad++ and akelpad for text editing.

sample text : `hello,this is a test.are you ready?`

search for : `(?<=[a-z,.?! ])([,.?!])(?=[a-z])`

replace with : `\1`

replace result : `hello, this is a test. are you ready?`

It works as intended, only if I replace them all, but if I click on replace button, nothing happens. It navigates to the next match as if I click on find.

[refer to this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CiPY.png)

It happens both in npp and akelpad. Why does this happen and what's the solution I should try?

Thank you!

Comment: Try clicking 'replace all'. This is probably a problem with your editor, since the regex is fine. See: https://regex101.com/r/4E0mu1/1; it matches properly

Comment: Just use `([,.?!])(?=[A-Za-z])`. Or `([a-z,.?! ][,.?!])(?=[a-zA-Z])`

Comment: I get the same behaviour, probably a Npp bug.. You can signal it to the developpers of Npp.

Comment: Thank you all for the ideas. I get the result I wish for anyway. but sometimes I need to make a final  inspection so replace one at a time is very important to me. I tried Wiktor's alternatives and it seems to be the best I can try for now, although I still would be happier if I could use lookbehind subex and just get only the match highlighted for clearer view.

Comment: @katovic You do not need a lookbehind if you do not need overlapping matches. In this case, you do not.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug since the regex is fine.

All similar problems in Notepad++ and other suchlike editors can be solved by capturing as more as you can.

In your case, you may turn the lookbehind into a consuming pattern:

```
([a-z,.?! ][,.?!])(?=[a-zA-Z])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Now, when replacing with `\1` , you will get the desired behavior, i.e. a space will get appended to the match value.

Demo:

[image]

Comment: good. maybe it has something to do with the use of lookbehind regex and I don't know why. maybe bug, maybe it's just how it works?

Comment: @katovic It is a bug for sure. The point of `Replace` is to move to the location of the match (to show you where it is) and then replace it once you press it again and go to the next match.

Answer (score 0):

If this is only what you want, try this ....

Find what: `[,.]`
Replace with: `$0`